# json schema is not valid in logic app Prase Json

Tags: azure-logic-apps

i need to define json schema for a json file which i am getting from the blob container
that json file sometimes has single data, sometimes it have multiple data that json automatically creates from our pipeline
**i am getting an error in Prase Json in logic app**

example of a single entry

```
{
        "Environment": "DEV",
        "Application": "OTHER",
        "Keyvault": "keyvault-name",
        "Certificate": "test",
        "Expires": "2023-10-13T20:18:36+00:00"
 }
```

Example: multiple data

```
[
    {
        "Environment": "DEV",
        "Application": "OTHER",
        "Keyvault": "keyvault-name",
        "Certificate": "test",
        "Expires": "2023-10-13T20:18:36+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Environment": "DEV",
        "Application": "OTHER",
        "Keyvault": "keyvault-name1",
        "Certificate": "test1",
        "Expires": "2023-10-13T20:18:36+00:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Parse Json Schema:`**

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Environment": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Application": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Keyvault": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Certificate": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Expires": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Environment",
            "Application",
            "Keyvault",
            "Certificate",
            "Expires"
        ]
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`With single entry also worked for me:`**

**`Design is same but in input added [] :`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Conclusion :`**

Different json uses different schema, if one single json is coming also you need to send it in array format like below because then you can send multipart json as an input:

```
[{
        "Environment": "DEV",
        "Application": "OTHER",
        "Keyvault": "keyvault-name",
        "Certificate": "test",
        "Expires": "2023-10-13T20:18:36+00:00"
 }]
```

So, schema depends on input, if input is array then schema also contains array schema,you need to add [] for single json also.

Comment: when I add [] it does not work for multiple json entry

Comment: It worked for me,see the output screenshots, You need to add only when it is single entry, it is multiple json, you have given array of json before only right.

Comment: how to check that json is a single entry or multiple entry

Comment: You can simple add an paction which only works if the parse json action fails, then the other parse json action will work like this https://i.imgur.com/nncbQvQ.png and this works if you change the runafter to Failed in code of second Parse json https://i.imgur.com/myZnb6w.png, with this both type of data will work

Comment: I need to get a parse JSON body to filter the array. How can I get it?
I need to add it to the filter array, or is there any way to get it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpCId.png

Comment: No it doesnot have filter parameter

Answer (score 0):

The strength of `Parse JSON` is that you can get the dynamic content as output.  If you don't have that then you need to use expressions to do what you need.

The thing with your dataset though is that you're not only after the dynamic content, you want to be able to process it consistently.  The best way to achieve that is to treat the data as an array each time.

However, as you've pointed out, the data may already be in an array format.  Given your data is a string to start with, you can apply this approach in the `Parse JSON` step ...

[image: Flow]

The first step is just a string representation of your data, much like that which you get from blob storage.

The second step is the `Parse JSON` step with these parameters ...

#### Expression

```
json(concat('[', replace(replace(variables('JSON String'), '[', ''), ']', ''), ']'))
```

Essentially, what that does is take the string, remove the opening and closing array brackets (`[` and `]`) and then throws the brackets back on the outside of the string value and parses it as JSON.

This approach results in an array everytime which means a consistent set of steps beneath the `Parse JSON` step, i.e. you'll always be dealing with an array from that point on.

#### Schema

```
{
    "items": {
        "properties": {
            "Application": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Certificate": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Environment": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Expires": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Keyvault": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "Environment",
            "Application",
            "Keyvault",
            "Certificate",
            "Expires"
        ],
        "type": "object"
    },
    "type": "array"
}
```

It is actually possible to have the schema setup in a way where it will accept both the single object AND the array at the same time but that will remove the resulting dynamic content and kind of defeat the purpose of using a `Parse JSON` step.

The approach I've provided will work nicely for you.